# After 24 hours from creation ORDER BY ASC

Tags: sql

The values are ordered DESC at first:

```
post_createdAt
--------------
2016-05-12 00:03:00
2016-05-12 00:02:00
2016-05-12 00:01:00
```

After 24 hours from their creation, I want to order them ASC:

**2016-05-13 00:02:00**

```
post_createdAt
--------------    
2016-05-12 00:03:00
2016-05-12 00:01:00
2016-05-12 00:02:00
```

**2016-05-13 00:03:00**

```
post_createdAt
--------------       
2016-05-12 00:01:00
2016-05-12 00:02:00
2016-05-12 00:03:00
```

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly you want to do. It may be a good idea to elaborate on what exactly you want to do. Please tell us from where (which application/framework) you are doing your SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't reorder a table unless you delete all of the data and replace it. Why don't you just create a view where your data is ordered the way you want it *at all times*.

### Edit

If you want a record to appear first for 24 hours, you can do that through a view.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE post_createdAt >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
ORDER BY post_createdAt DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE post_createdAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
ORDER BY post_createdAt ASC
```

I don't know MySql, but this is what I pieced together through the 'net.

Comment: I fetch the data with PHP from the DB, and I want to keep the latest entry first in the list for 24 hours, then to put it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are looking for

```
select * from (select top 1000 post_createdAt from [TableName] where post_createdAt < DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE()) order by post_createdAt desc) as table1

union all

select * from (select top 1000 post_createdAt from [TableName] where post_createdAt  > DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE()) order by post_createdAt asc) as table2
```